# Mockito calling its mock when Mockito.when() is called?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

Setup like this:

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
  mockAddressClient();
}

private void mockAddressClient() {
  Mockito
    .when(addressClient.addAddress(Mockito.any()))
    .thenAnswer(
      in -> {
        de.vbg.suvi.api.address.v1.model.Address adr = in.getArgument(0);
        de.vbg.suvi.api.address.v1.model.ValueAddress values = adr.getValues();
        AddressResponse addressResponse =
          new AddressResponse()
            .id(UUID.randomUUID())
            .streetLine1(values.getStreetLine1())
            .streetLine2(values.getStreetLine2())
            .streetNumber(values.getStreetNumber())
            .zipCode(values.getZipCode())
            .city(values.getCity())
            .country(values.getCountry());
        addresses.put(addressResponse.getId(), addressResponse);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(addressResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    });
}

@Test
void postFullAccidentReport_firstWitnessAddressStreetNumberMissing() {
  /*
   * Given
   */
  final String placeId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  AccidentReport accidentReport = createFullAccidentReport();
  accidentReport.getFirstWitness().getPerson().getAddress().setPlaceId(placeId);
  accidentReport.getFirstWitness().getPerson().getAddress().setValues(null);
  Mockito.when(addressClient.addAddress(Mockito.argThat(a -> a.getPlaceId().equals(placeId))))
    .thenThrow(
      new ValidationException(
        List.of(
          new SuviFieldValidationError(
            ViolationCode.INVALID, "message", "streetNumber"))));

  /*
   * When
   */
  ResponseEntity<ValidationProblem> response =
    postAccidentReport(accidentReport, ValidationProblem.class);

  /*
   * Then
   */
  Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, response.getStatusCode());
  Assertions.assertNotNull(response.getBody());
  ValidationProblem validationProblem = response.getBody();
  FieldViolation fieldViolation = validationProblem.getViolations().get(0);
  Assertions.assertEquals(
    "firstWitness.person.address.placeId.streetNumber", fieldViolation.getField());
}
```

Now when running my test I receive a `NullPointerException` in the method `mockAddressClient()` on `adr.getValues()`. Checking the call trace it looks as if the NPE is thrown on the line `Mockito.when()` in my test method. As if the Mockito is calling its own mock.

Has somebody experienced this before? Is the setup wrong? What is the way around it?

EDIT:
Annotation for the Mock is `@MockBean`.
Return type of `addAddress()` is `ResponseEntity<AddressResponse>`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at de.vbg.suvi.claim.api.ClaimControllerTest.lambda$mockAddressClient$18(ClaimControllerTest.java:2308 undefined)
   at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.StubbedInvocationMatcher.answer(StubbedInvocationMatcher.java:40 undefined)
   at org.mockito.internalr.MockHandlerImpl.handle.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:99 undefined)
   at org.mockito.internalr.NullResultGuardian.handle.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29 undefined)
   at org.mockito.internalr.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:33 undefined)
   at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:82 undefined)
   at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:56 undefined)
   at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptAbstract(MockMethodInterceptor.java:157 undefined)
   at de.vbg.suvi.claim.clients.AddressClient$MockitoMock$2090955218.addAddress(Unknown Source)
   at de.vbg.suvi.claim.api.ClaimControllerTest.postFullAccidentReport_firstWitnessAddressStreetNumberMissing(ClaimControllerTest.java:825 undefined)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131 undefined)
   at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84 undefined)
   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84 undefined)
   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96 undefined)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75 undefined)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99 undefined)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79 undefined)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75 undefined)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61 undefined)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94 undefined)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133 undefined)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 undefined)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 undefined)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48 undefined)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130 undefined)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630 undefined)
   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56 undefined)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832 undefined)
```

Comment: How is `addressClient` created? A normal `@Mock` or `Mockito.mock`? And what is the return type of `addAddress`? If you can add the stacktrace that might also help.

Comment: Added the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this construction your `thenThrow` setup indeed calls the method on the mock, instead of setting it up.

You can use the alternative mock setup to fix this, for example (incomplete example for readability):

```java
Mockito.doThrow(myException).when(addressClient).addAddress(matchers)
```

Validated this in one of my own projects with Mockito.

If Mockito then complains that this mocking constuction is deemed unnecessary (a matcher on `any` and a specific matcher on `argThat`), you can set it up with `lenient` enabled:

```java
Mockito.lenient().doThrow(myException).when(addressClient).addAddress(matchers)
```

From https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-unnecessary-stubbing-exception

This is basically because in your `@BeforeEach` you setup a general answer, and in the specific test `postFullAccidentReport_firstWitnessAddressStreetNumberMissing` you want it to throw an `Exception` instead.
So the first setup is actually not used in this test method.

My guess is that you have other test methods that do use the general setup, but it would be `cleaner` to have the correct setup for each method.

Comment: Hm, I tried this before, but couldn't get it to work. However, I tried again after you said it worked and found had a problem elsewhere for your solution to work. Working now! Thanks a lot!